# How to interact between tables with SQL for filtering

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL tables that look like:

table **user_activity**

| user | page | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | mainPage | 2021-01-10 04:37:14 |
| 1 | mainPage | 2021-01-10 10:37:24 |
| 2 | mainPage | 2021-01-10 20:37:44 |
| 3 | mainPage | 2021-01-10 20:10:14 |
| 4 | mainPage | 2021-01-11 00:02:04 |
| 2 | secondPage | 2021-01-12 00:03:04 |
| 4 | mainPage | 2021-01-13 00:31:04 |
| 5 | mainPage | 2021-01-14 20:23:04 |
| 2 | mainPage | 2021-01-15 10:37:04 |

table **users**

| user | registration date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-10 04:37:14 |
| 2 | 2021-01-10 20:37:44 |
| 3 | 2021-01-10 20:10:14 |
| 4 | 2021-01-11 00:02:04 |
| 5 | 2021-01-14 20:23:04 |

I´m trying to get the amount of times that the users that were registered (registration date) after the 01-01-2021 visited the **mainPage**.
I´ve tried:

`mycursor.execute("SELECT user, COUNT(*) FROM user_activity WHERE name = 'mainPage' GROUP BY user;")`

I know how to get the amount of times that a user visited the mainPage, but I don´t know how to relate between tables in SQL, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add a join conditition and check for date in where

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT user, COUNT(*) 
        FROM user_activity
        INNER JOIN users ON user.id = user_activity.user
        WHERE user_activity.name = 'mainPage' 
        AND user.registrazione_date > str_to_date('01-01-2021','%d-%m-%Y' )
        GROUP BY user;")
```

Answer (score 0):

To join 2 tables based on a common attribute in your case "user" you can do this:

SELECT * FROM user_activity inner join users on users.user = user_activity.user;

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables like below,

```
SELECT u.user, COUNT(ua.user)
FROM `users` u
LEFT JOIN `user_activity` ua ON ua.user = u.user 
AND ua.name = 'mainPage' 
AND ua.registrazione_date > DATE('01-01-2021')
GROUP BY u.user;
```